# Import XML products to Prestashop

Tags: php, xml, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am currently working on a XML plugin that imports automatically a large number of products from external source (a distributor) to my Prestashop. The XML importer works fine - it adds all the product data to my shop's database, but I have problem uploading the images. I have the URL for my external image, stored in a PHP variable in the plugin. The Prestashop uses 7 different sizes of the single image when uploaded (not from the XML plugin but from its own admin panel when uploading a product). My XML uploader is located in **tools/xmlplugin**. The upload function has this basic structure:

```
    myUploadFunction($external_product_ID)
    {
         ..upload to db functions here...
         $external_image_url_path;   
         $external_image_name;       //ex. image_001.jpg
    }
```

Can you help me with the logistics of uploading the images and creating several different-sized images to the image folder of Prestashop.

PS: The XML plugin is not connected to the core of Prestashop (only to the database). And I cannot understand the URL structure of the profuct images of Prestashop.

Any ideas?

Comment: witch version of Prestashop are you using ?

Comment: Image names are rewritten in `.htaccess`. Also, the correct way to import images would be to deffer the task of creating and uploading them and the product has been saved to the DB. Importing images in synchronious modes takes wya too much time

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a new entry for your image in database.
If you look at Prestashop Image Class it stores images under directories created from your image id. You need to split each number of your image id to get the path. Here is Prestashop Image Class method :

```
/**
 * Returns the path to the folder containing the image in the new filesystem
 *
 * @param mixed $id_image
 * @return string path to folder
 */
public static function getImgFolderStatic($id_image)
{
    if (!is_numeric($id_image)) {
        return false;
    }
    $folders = str_split((string)$id_image);
    return implode('/', $folders).'/';
}
```

In defines.inc.php `_PS_IMG_DIR_` defines your image folder (default: `/img/`) and `_PS_PROD_IMG_DIR_` defines your product image folder (default: `p/`). by default the folder for product image is then `/img/p/`.

If an image has for id 927 and for name "test.jpg" it will be stored under `/img/p/9/2/7/927.jpg`

First try this for a few products and then in Prestashop BackOffice go to `Preferences > Images > regenerate thumbnails (at the bottom of the page)`. Prestashop should generate each products image sizes for you.

Please let me know if it doesn't work or if you need more instructions.